# Specifying return type of a Public Function is necessary or not?

Tags: vb.net, function, return, return-value

I have a snippet here:

```
  Dim a As Integer = 10 '<--- an integer variable inintialized with 10
  a = byreferenceFun(a) '<---calling a function and assign the return value 

  Public Function byreferenceFun(ByVal a As Integer) '<-- function , no return type is specified
      byreferenceFun = 30 ' <-- return 30 to the calling function
 End Function
```

Their is no return type is specified in the function but it works fine and `returns` integer and string values;

My **Question** is that Specifying return type of a `Public Function` is necessary or not? or it is because of the reason `function that should return a value`?

Comment: It should be required with Option Strict turned on. Otherwise it will infer the type. You probably don't have an issue since you are only returning one type. It will probably return `Object` if you return different types.

Comment: What bugs me most when someone asks me to help him solving issues in his code is inference and implicit casting. I'm OK with uncommented codes, but the ones that don't declare variable and return types are a hell to debug. It's a comment, not an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary in the sense that you can turn option strict off, but turning option strict off is considered by most to be a bad practice(unless of course you know exactly why you are doing it...)

If you do decide to turn option strict off and disclude the as clause on your function, then your function will return an 'Object', which is the base class that all objects inherit from, and you can cast that object to the type you are assigning it to.

The only problem is that if your function returns an object, and that object is of type "string", then when you assign the output of your function to an integer, the compiler will show no error until runtime, then you would get an invalid cast exception.

example:

```
Sub Calculate()
    Dim result As Integer = GetCalculation()
End Sub
Function GetCalculation()
    Return "hello world"
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

From: [Function Statement (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx)

> returntype - Required if **Option Strict** is **On**. Data type of the value
>   returned by this procedure.